# Maven project execution command

Tags: java, maven

Below is my sample class file:

```
package org.foo.tutorial;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

In order to execute the project (maven framework) we run:

```
>java -cp Something-1.0.SNAPSHOT.jar org.foo.tutorial.APP
```

The above command works fine and gives me the output 'HELLO WORLD'.

However, if I leave out the third argument in the above command (org.foo.tutorial.APP) I get the following error:

```
 Error: Could not find or load main class target.MavenTutorialApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

My question is:

Why should the groupId and app name matter when I am supplying the entire 'jar' file ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is a bit misleading. Your [`java`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) command is incorrect since you don't specify a *class*. The `Something-1.0.SNAPSHOT.jar` is meant to be part of the `-cp` option but `java` is interpreting it as the *class*.

That's how `java` behaves

> The `java` command starts a Java application. It does this by starting a
>   Java runtime environment, **loading a specified class, and calling that
>   class's main method.**

If your `.jar` file contains an [entry point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) specified by a `Main-Class` header in the manifest, then you can simply run

```
java -jar Something-1.0.SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer your question.

> Why should the groupId and app name matter when I am supplying the
>   entire 'jar' file ?

Lets divide the question into smaller part -

`What is group id?` - The id of the project's group.

`What is artifactId?` - The id of the artifact (project) and off course version is part of default artifact name.

While running a java program under jvm there are no such effect that how you built  jar, for example it is produced by maven or gradle build process or even command line.

Things that matter is jar file and entry point or the class where main reside.

---

This may be out of scope of this question, but i felt relevant.

To run java program from jar file, you can explicitly mention like above. Also you can create executable jar file by adding manifest file, where it define the entry point of the executable -

Main-Class: org.foo.tutorial.APP

1. [How to create executable jar?](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html)
2. Also maven `maven-assembly-plugin` helps to package executable jar.
   [help](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/08/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-in-maven/#.VfmQvWSqqko)